# Find time name between two dates

Tags: mysql, date

Is there any function that will give me the name of passed time with two dates in mysql? for example, after i've wrote a post then the page redirects me to the post page it must say " posted 4 seconds before", and afte five minutes later it will say posted 5 minutes before". If the time bigger than 60 minutes it will say xx hours before ...
15 days later it must say 2 weeks ago.

Something like wordpress meta info.

Same as time on my nick name at to right bottom of this post

Comment: No. You'll have to roll your own. A case expression could pull this off, but it will be a little nasty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I want

```
function formatDateDiff($start, $end=null) {
if(!($start instanceof DateTime)) {
    $start = new DateTime($start);
}

if($end === null) {
    $end = new DateTime();
}

if(!($end instanceof DateTime)) {
    $end = new DateTime($start);
}

$interval = $end->diff($start);
$doPlural = function($nb,$str){
    if ($nb > 1) {
        switch ($str) {
            case 'Yıl':
            case 'Ay':
            case 'Gün':
                return $str.'e';
            case 'Saat':
            case 'Dakika':
            case 'Saniye':
                return $str.'n';
        }
    } else
        return $str;
}; // adds plurals

$format = array();
if($interval->y !== 0) {
    $format[] = "%y ".$doPlural($interval->y, "Yıl");
}
if($interval->m !== 0) {
    $format[] = "%m ".$doPlural($interval->m, "Ay");
}
if($interval->d !== 0) {
    $format[] = "%d ".$doPlural($interval->d, "Gün");
}
if($interval->h !== 0) {
    $format[] = "%h ".$doPlural($interval->h, "Saat");
}
if($interval->i !== 0) {
    $format[] = "%i ".$doPlural($interval->i, "Dakika");
}
if($interval->s !== 0) {
    $format[] = "%s ".$doPlural($interval->s, "Saniye");
}

if(count($format)==0 || (count($format)==1 && $interval->s !== 0)) {
    return "Az Önce";
}

// We use the two biggest parts
if(count($format) > 1) {
    $format = array_shift($format).", ".array_shift($format);
} else {
    $format = array_pop($format);
}

// Prepend 'since ' or whatever you like
return $interval->format($format);
```

}

Reference Address: https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Thank you so much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write this on scripting side. If you are using PHP you can use the following code block to convert unixtime to relative phrase.

```php
function relative_date($date)
{
    $diff = time() - $date;
    if ($diff < 0) {
        return "just now";
    } else {
        $app = "ago";
    }

    $t_diff = $diff;

    $days = floor($diff / 3600 / 24);
    $diff = $diff - ( $days * 3600 * 24 );
    $hours = floor($diff / 3600);
    $diff = $diff - ( $hours * 3600 );
    $minutes = floor($diff / 60);
    $diff = $diff - ( $minutes * 60 );
    $seconds = $diff;

    if ($t_diff > 60 * 60 * 24) {
        $str = ( $days . ' days' );
    } else if ($t_diff > 60) {
        $str = ( $hours ? "{$hours} hours" : "" ) . ( $minutes ? " $minutes minutes" : "" );
    } else {
        $str = ( $seconds ) . " seconds";
    }
    $str = $str . " $app";

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: It gives "A non well formed numeric value encountered" error. I think it is because of date format. How about if I want to show the time as weeks and years.